# Can I set the 'always on top' flag from designer in Qt?

Tags: qt, always-on-top

Can I do this from the property sheet for the window in UI View?

Currently I'm setting the always on top flag in the constructor of my QMainDialog:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

Comment: Any app that does "always on top" gets deleted from my system.

Comment: Well that app is for personal use. It's a transparent always on top window that shows you hex to dec and dec to hex to any number that goes to the clipboard. Oh, and do still have Task Manager on your system :)